# Sending an XML format data to google map from android

Tags: android, networking

i want to send my MapView geolocation and user data from my android to a website using Google maps.

How can i send my data in an XML file to my server? or is there other ways better than sending it?

Answer (score 1):

I use a JSON object and send the string e.g. : {"lon":-4253447,"lat":55864243} and then parse it back into a JSON object.

Comment: by sending a string {"lon":-4253447,"lat":55864243} and append it to an xml file then sending it to the webserver? or just append it straight to the xml file residing in my server?  any reference that i can go with? a bit blurry here.

Comment: you are using JSON or XML. I'd prefer JSON for performance reasons.

Comment: i'm appending it to an xml file and POST it back to my web server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a brainfreeze because it's sunday, but why would you want to send an XML file? Why not just send your value pairs using POST or GET?

Comment: i'm using google maps to read the datas from my android and i want those data's to stay in my web